# VBA FORr loop, increasing the To maxValue value, doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a for loop like this in my vba code:

```
maxValues = 10
for i = 1 to maxValues
   do something...
if true then
   maxValues = maxValues + 1
next
```

I've gone step by step and i never goes above the original maxValues value, is it not possible to change the maxValues? Really need it in the function in this case.

Would be glad if someone can clarify :)

Comment: It's considered bad practise to increment the loop counter directly - if you need to do something like this then use a different type of loop.  " Really need it in the function in case" - in case of what?

Comment: Basicly it's to fill a list with X values, so I run a for loop X times, but the user might not want words with < than Y chars, so I do not put that item on the list, so I'd like to increased the maxValue of the for loop so it runs one more time to get another value. ** in this case **

Comment: you should use a do while statement.

Comment: Okk I'll try that then. Thanks!

Comment: Also your `if` statement was incomplete,  (it either needs an `End If`, or else put the `if` and `then` lines on the same line.)

Comment: Yeah yeah the if was good. I just did not know about this For restrain, I read that it's because VBA treats the For values as a Range or something along those lines. I did use the While statement and it worked perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't update the For value once it's set, so had to use a While statement.

Something like:

```
 maxValues = 10
 i = 1    
 do while i <= maxValues
     if true then 
         maxValues = maxValues + 1
     end if
     i = i + 1
 loop
```

Thanks for the replies.